# Delete user from database when it's removed from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, active-directory

I have a website built in ASP.net, c# and SQL SERVER which has a table in the database with the users information.

I would like to know how to check if the user was removed from the Active Directory to proceed to delete from the database.

I don't know if this can be done instantly or it's better to check it one time per day and then proceed to delete de user.

I have read [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065918/syncronizing-database-from-active-directory) but it's not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check once a day, it would probably be easiest to get a list of all users from Active Directory, then query your database to see which ones are in your database that aren't in the list you just got from Active Directory. Then delete them.

Comment: @JulianMoreno You mean the exact code to do all of that? I can give you some pseudo code

Comment: An example using **c#**.